# Anchor tag update div without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this div which includes an anchor tag that loads a php script that essentially adds information to a database and returns back to this page.  I want to use this achor tag to run that php script update the database and refresh this div without reloading the page.  The php script need those two variables title and vote which used with the php $_GET[] function.  Can this be done, and if so how? I have searched everywhere and no script seems to work.  Will provide more information if needed. Thanks so much will give credit to everyone who helps.

```
      <div class='like_box'>
                <a href='#' class='counter' ><img src='img/like.png' class='vote'></a><p class='vote_text'>$like_num</p>
                <p style='color: #fff;'>$like_username</p>
      </div>
```

I've tried something like this

```
        <script>
           $('a.counter').click( function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              vote.php?vote=like&title=$title
           });
        </script>
```

Comment: when you use href like this, it is a GET request that refreshes the page. Use ajax instead using onclick on the anchor tag and doing preventDefault.

Comment: is there a way to do this, and still update the div even though you preventDefault?

Comment: of course, on success of the ajax request update your variables $like_num and $like_username...

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but do you think you could write like a little bit of psuedo-code or something to show me how to do this if its not too much trouble I've just tried a few different options and I can't get anything to work. Really appreciate it.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: ok I'll edit this to show you.

Comment: There are examples in [the jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: yea that's where I've gotten that code. No success for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 <div class='like_box'>
                <a href='#' class='counter' ><img src='img/like.png' class='vote'></a><p class='vote_text'>$like_num</p>
                <p class="vote_text1" style='color: #fff;'>$like_username</p>
      </div>
```

In the javascript side (jquery)

```
$(".like_box a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
    url: 'vote.php?vote=like&title=$title', 
    success: function(result){
            // update $like_num and $like_username here
            // if you do not have them binded use this
            $('.like_box p.vote_text').text('<value from result>');
            $('.like_box p.vote_text1').text('<value from result>');
        }});
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time.